# Why am I getting 'Cannot GET' in localhost for Vue npm run serve

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I installed Vite build tool for Vue and when I ran it (`npm run serve`), I got an error that generated the following message

> "Missing script: "serve"".

After a little research, I learned that my `package.json` was missing the `serve` key.

[image]

After I added it (`"serve": "vite preview"`) and ran it, I received the following error in the browser

> "Cannot GET /"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`vite preview` (previously as `serve` in Vue2's CLI) only checks the static result when your app is already **built** with `npm run build`.

To run it locally, use `vite` instead of `vite preview` (which is listed as `npm run dev` in your package.json config).

More info is available on [Vite's documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#building-the-app).